# Cannot apply indexing to an expression type object

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a very simple project in C# but i haven't don't much since i encounter errors as i progress. I do have a class called CUSTOMER and contains a few line of codes.

```
 public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    public Customer(DataRow row)
    {
        this.FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
    }


    public List<Customer> GetCustomer()
    {
        List<Customer> c=new List<Customer>();
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        Dal.GetDataTable(dt, "select * from customer");
        foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
        {
            c.Add(new Customer(row["FirstName"]));  //Error here
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

This code is pretty straightforward i believe, i want to retrieve a list of customers from a `DataTable`. According to the compiler:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Thank you.

Comment: you are trying to pull the `FirstName` column out of your row twice, and its throwing off your types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You error is here :

```
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
{
     c.Add(new Customer(row["FirstName"]));
}
```

You should change it to match the constructor:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     c.Add(new Customer(row));
}
```

You constructor accepts a `DataRow`, so you need to pass a row and not an object( `row["FirstName"]`returns an object which is the `FirstName` value for the current row ).

You also need to implicitly specify the type of the foreach variable `(DataRow row in dt.Rows`)

Comment: Thanks for helping me but sad to say it doesn't work.
https://s32.postimg.org/p0vb589g5/Untitled.png

Comment: @DikongPrigm just change `var row` to `DataRow row`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to iterate Rows via foreach loop and got the same error. Use 'DataRow' variable type instead of 'var'.

```
foreach(var row in table.Rows)
    Console.WriteLine(row["fName"]);
} //This one gives error

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    Console.WriteLine(row["fName"]);
} //This one works fine.
```